# App Engine FilterPredicate returning nothing when querying for string

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Java 8 to build a hobby project on Google App Engine but my Query return null even though there entity exists in the datastore on my localhost.

From datastore

```
key: aglub19hcHBfaWRyGAsSC0dyb2NlcnlMaXN0GICAgICAgMAJDA ID/Name: 5348024557502464   created: Tue Dec 04 22:06:11 CET 2018   owner: 185804764220139100000
```

The "owner" Id I'm getting using the UserServiceFactory and the id is correct, checked it several times.

Here is how I query the entity I need

```
Query q = new Query("GroceryList")
          .setFilter(new FilterPredicate("owner", FilterOperator.EQUAL, currentUser.getUserId()));

        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
        Entity result = pq.asSingleEntity();
```

But the entity is null, nothing is fetched. I used https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/2e5996c68440134a79f1511c57529fa5cf987628/appengine-java8/datastore/src/test/java/com/example/appengine/QueriesTest.java#L787 as a reference.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The "owner" string you are using as the property name in your code (starts with lowercase) doesn't match the key from the Datastore (starts with uppercase). 
Try again changing the property name to "Owner" and see if that works

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But I was the one typing Owner with capital O, its not how its named in the store

Comment: From the code about it's hard to tell what could be the issue. Maybe you could add more code which reproduces the issue. Also what does the `currentUser.getUserId()` returns and what type is the result?